# Lexing a String in Java with Regex

Tags: java, regex, lexer

For some reason the while loop is only going through one time, picking up a `NUMBER` and then exiting. Does anyone have any idea why it isn't lexing the rest of the String? All I had was an input of `1 + 2`. Any help is much appreciated!!

```
public Lexer(String input) throws TokenMismatchException {
        tokens = new ArrayList<Token>();

        // Lexing logic begins here
        StringBuffer tokenPatternsBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (Type type : Type.values())
            tokenPatternsBuffer.append(String.format("|(?<%s>%s)", type.name(), type.pattern));
        Pattern tokenPatterns = Pattern.compile(new String(tokenPatternsBuffer.substring(1)));

        // Begin matching tokens
        Matcher matcher = tokenPatterns.matcher(input.replaceAll(" ", ""));
        while (matcher.find()) {
            if (matcher.group(Type.NUMBER.name()) != null) {
                tokens.add(new Token(Type.NUMBER, matcher.group(Type.NUMBER.name())));
                continue;
            } else if (matcher.group(Type.OPERATOR.name()) != null) {
                tokens.add(new Token(Type.OPERATOR, matcher.group(Type.OPERATOR.name())));
                continue;
            } else if (matcher.group(Type.UNIT.name()) != null) {
                tokens.add(new Token(Type.UNIT, matcher.group(Type.UNIT.name())));
                continue;
            } else if (matcher.group(Type.PARENTHESES.name()) != null) {
                tokens.add(new Token(Type.PARENTHESES, matcher.group(Type.PARENTHESES.name())));
                continue;
            } else {
                throw new TokenMismatchException();
            }
        }
    }

enum Type {
    NUMBER("[0-9]+.*[0-9]*"), OPERATOR("[*|/|+|-]"), UNIT("[in|pt]"), PARENTHESES("[(|)]");

    public final String pattern;

    private Type(String pattern) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern:

```
"[0-9]+.*[0-9]*"
```

matches one or more digits, followed by zero or more of *any* character, followed by zero or more digits.  The dot is a special character in regexes that means "any character".  If you're trying to match a decimal point, you need to put a backslash before the dot:

```
"[0-9]+\\.*[0-9]*"
```

(The backslash is doubled because it's in a Java string literal.)  It appears to work on `"1 + 2"` if that one fix is made.  However, some of your other patterns show some misunderstanding of what `[]` does in a regex.  This is a "character class" that matches any of the characters you list in between the brackets, except that `-` can be used for a range of characters (like `0-9`).  So

```
"[*|/|+|-]"
```

matches any of the characters `*`, `|`, `/`, `+`, `-` (the `|` does not mean "or" inside square brackets).  `-` isn't treated as a range operator here since it's last, but it's probably best to get in the habit of using `\` in front of it anyway, so you want

```
"[*/+\\-]"
```

Similarly,

```
"[in|pt]"
```

matches one of the five characters `i`, `n`, `|`, `p`, `t`--certainly not what you want.  You probably want

```
"(in|pt)"
```

which matches either `"in"` or `"pt"`; the parentheses may not be necessary in your case, but in a different case, they may be necessary to prevent some other characters from being included in one of the alternatives when the pattern is included in a larger string.